# Setting number format using Excel object quickly

Tags: vba, excel, number-formatting

I am writing 12,000 records with 46 columns, as a production report, to an excel file.  The worksheet is not displayed while it is filled with data.

Previous StackOverflow information taught me to use arrays of objects to put values in ranges for speed.  I had hoped this worked for formatting the values as well.

Code snip:

```
objExcel.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual
objExcel.ScreenUpdating = False

dcel = objWS.Range(objWS.Cells(rowdatastart, 1), objWS.Cells(rowdataend, nProdReportCol.ProdReportColCount - 2))

dcel.Value = aobj

dcel.NumberFormat = bobj

objExcel.ScreenUpdating = True
objExcel.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic
```

aobj and bobj are object(,) arrays that fit the range. bobj contains strings such as "h:mma/p" to display time as "12:23a", and "0.00" to show numbers as "53/25".

The "dcel.value = aobj" takes half a second.
The "dcel.NumberFormat = bobj" takes 38 seconds.

Any suggestion for what I've missed/misunderstood?  I'd rather a 7 second report (start excel, write, save, close excel) not take 45 seconds because I want the numbers/dates/times to appear as I choose.

Comment: Won't work for format.  Perhaps you can create range objects so that all of the cells requiring a certain `bobj` format can be formatted at once; or perhaps you could use conditional formatting to set an entire range at once. Since your code is working, this might be best on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each column has its own format then try formatting per whole column.  Also for each column do not use an array, if the formats are identical then you can just use a single string.

Do so for each column.

Please attempt and provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimentation, I found the same solution as S Meaden. As only 14 of the 46 columns are not "General", I collected the column numbers for dates, times and 2-decimal numeric. Looping through each of these, gen a range for the 12000 records and 1 column, set the format.  This takes about half a second for all the columns.

Odd that setting a row of 46 cells using a 46 object array takes so much longer than 12000 cells in a column, but there you are.

Thanks everyone.